# nuxt generated dist file return net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying to generate a static site of my nuxtjs app and then upload it to an s3 bucket to serve.

I ran `npm run generate` and it generated the `dist` folder.

I copied the `dist` folder to the s3 bucket `s3.exampleaws.com/webapp/latest`

Now the main `index.html` file should be here `s3.exampleaws.com/webapp/latest/index.html`

When I access this page, nothing is visible and on the console, I'm getting the following errors:

> 4 GET file:///_nuxt/f69388b45d6b2e9cc542.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Even if I open the `index.html` file on the `dist` folder in a browser, it still shows the same error.

Is there any way to display the site on the browser?

My `nuxt.config.js` file looks like this:

```
export default {
  mode: 'spa',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/tailwind.css',
    '~/assets/css/all.css'
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
    '@nuxtjs/toast'
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: './tailwind.config.js'
      }
    },
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.output.globalObject = 'this'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: shouldn;t this s3.exampleaws.com/webapp/latest/index.html should be s3.exampleaws.com/webapp/latest/dist/index.html

Comment: ^ I copied only the contents of the `dist` file.

Comment: Also, even on the local system, if I open the `index.html` file in the `dist` folder, it shows the same error

Comment: have you checked this link : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploy-a-nuxt-app-to-s3-in-5-minutes-515a161eb74f/

Comment: Yes I checked it. I don't think its about the s3. May be something to do with the `nuxt.config.js` file.